# Error updating Visual Studio 2017 15.6.2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-setup

I was trying to update VS 2017 to 15.6.2 version. As usual VS asked me to update the Installer. But the Installer updating failed and now, when I try to launch the VS updating again, I get this error message:

> Error loading vs_installershell.exe: No signature was present in the subject.

Anyone has ever seen this before? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft recommends the following procedure in this case:

1. Close the Visual Studio Installer.
2. Delete the Visual Studio Installer directory. Typically, the directory is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer`.
3. Run the Visual Studio Installer bootstrapper. You may find the bootstrapper in your Downloads folder with a file name that follows a `vs_[Visual Studio edition]__*.exe` pattern. If you don't find that application, you can download the bootstrapper by going to the [Visual Studio downloads page](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) and clicking Download for your edition of Visual Studio. Run the executable to reset your installation metadata.
4. Try to install or update Visual Studio again. If the Installer continues to fail, go to the next step.

There is also a bit of warning:

> Performing the following actions reinstalls the Visual Studio Installer files and resets the installation metadata.

But in the end, it reinstalls the VS Updater.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues