# vs_installershell.exe has an invalid signature visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I get an error while installing Visual Studio 2019 :

`vs_installershell.exe has an invalid signature visual studio 2019`

I tried to install the software on another computer without any success. I also tried to format my computer to install VS again but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I know it's not the same VS version but maybe you should have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49480199/4211681

Comment: which windows version do you have? if you have win7, make sure you have the SHA2 updates installed

Comment: windows 7 i have installed

Comment: have you installed Sp1 + all updates?